# http to https redirection through htaccess: incorrect redirection error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I need all HTTP requests to redirect to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^some-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://some-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(\.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(\?+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(/+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.html [L]
RewriteRule ^core/(install|temp|smarty|modules|languages|includes|functions|fonts|files|config|classes|cache|backup|tpl)/(.*) - [F]
RewriteRule ^data/(.+)\.(tpl\.html|php|php3|php4|php5|phtml|pl|cgi) - [F]
RewriteRule ^install_check\.html$ install.php?check=yes [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news\.html$ index.php?news=yes [L]
RewriteRule ^price\.html$ index.php?show_price=yes [L]
RewriteRule ^cart\.html$ index.php?shopping_cart=yes [L]
RewriteRule ^wide_search\.html$ index.php?search_with_change_category_ability=yes [L]
RewriteRule ^feedback\.html$ index.php?feedback=yes [L]
RewriteRule ^compare\.html$ index.php?comparison_products=yes [L]
RewriteRule ^page_([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?show_aux_page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product_([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?productID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category_([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?categoryID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category_([0-9]+)_offset_([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?categoryID=$1&offset=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category_([0-9]+)_show_all\.html$ index.php?categoryID=$1&show_all=yes [L]
RewriteRule ^show_news_([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?fullnews=$1 [L]

# BEGIN Articles
RewriteRule ^poleznoe/([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?fullarticles=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^poleznoe/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?articles=yes&offset=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^poleznoe/$ index.php?articles=yes [L]
# END Articles

RewriteRule ^google([a-z0-9_-]+).html$ google$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^yandex([a-z0-9_-]+).html$ yandex$1.html [L]

# BEGIN Human friendly URL's
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*).html$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=news [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=pages [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=category [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([^/]*)/$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$  $1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)_offset_([0-9]+))/$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=category&offset=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_show_all/$ index.php?uri=$1&uriFor=category&show_all=yes [L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?uri=$3&uriFor=product [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?uri=$2&uriFor=product [L]
# END Human friendly URL's
```

I've Googled and came across this solution several times:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but if I place it after `RewriteEngine On` or after `RewriteBase /` or anywhere near or between

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^some-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://some-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It gives me an incorrect redirection error when I load the page. Please, tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How is your SSL managed? Do you have a SSL cert installed directly on your application server? What do you mean by "incorrect redirection error"? Is the browser reporting a redirect loop?

Comment: yes - browser redirect loop is the problem. SSL is fine

Comment: "SLL is fine" - what does that mean? The fact that you are getting a redirect loop here strongly suggests that the SSL cert is not installed directly on your application server, but instead managed by a front-end proxy of some kind? (Cloudflare?)

Comment: again - SSL is fine. It means that web-site works fine on https. I am trying to setup 301 redirection from http to https. And this redirection does not work

Comment: If you check the network traffic, what are the redirects you are seeing? To help with debugging, try the following directive: `RewriteRule ^foo$ http://example.com/?https=%{HTTPS} [R,L]` (where `example.com` is literally `example.com`) and access `/foo`. What is `?https=????`?

Comment: Or.... check a dump of the `$_SERVER` array and check for the values of `HTTPS` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` (and maybe some other server-specific `X-....` headers?).

Comment: why would I do that? I know the redirection goes infinitely to the same page - https page. As I said - web-site works fine. Everything works fine. There are no errors on the web-site. There is only redirection error if I add the code that was offered on some other questions on stackoverflow. In other words - my code works fine, but it does not redirect to https if I go to any page with http - that's all I need: add something to my working htaccess provided above to make all http pages redirect to https

Comment: Because we need to find out why that didn't work and the correct directive to use for your server configuration. There is nothing "wrong" with the redirect code you posted - that code would work OK on most sites/servers that have SSL certs installed (which is why you've found the same code "several times" - it works). But it's not working on your site/server for some reason - which is "OK" - that code won't work on _every_ server config. But there is usually a good reason for it not working - which is why I was asking specifically _how_ the SSL cert is implemented, not whether "SSL works".

Comment: The most probable cause of the redirect loop is if the `HTTPS` server variable is not set, or not set as expected. If that is the case then we need to find another server variable to use. I would add `SERVER_PORT` to the list of `$_SERVER` variables to check.

Comment: oh! Never knew that, sorry. In fact $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is always empty, but $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] returns https when I am on https page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is always empty, but `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` returns https when I am on https page

This tells you that your SSL is managed by a front-end proxy server, not your application server. Your application server does not appear to have an SSL cert installed and is most probably serving a plain HTTP request over port 80 to the proxy server. The proxy server then serves a secure HTTPS response back to the client, so the clients request is secure.

What this means is that if your *application server* attempts to redirect HTTP to HTTPS by simply checking the standard server variables (ie. `HTTPS` or `SERVER_PORT`) then this is likely to fail with a redirect loop since `HTTPS` is always *off* and `SERVER_PORT` is always 80 - even after the redirect. (Note that the `HTTPS` Apache variable is likely to be "off", but this often translates to a PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` that is *empty* - that's just how PHP handles it.)

Note that the HTTP to HTTPS redirect could be performed in the front-end proxy instead, before it even gets to the application server. (Cloudflare does this with its *page rules*.)

Alternatively, you can examine the additional HTTP request headers that are set by the proxy server as the request is *forwarded* from the proxy to your application server. The `X-Forwarded-Proto` header (which is stored by PHP as `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']`) is set by the proxy server and tells you what protocol the client used to connect to your proxy.

So, bringing the canonical redirects together:

```
# www to non-www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# http to https redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

With the format of the directives you posted, the www to non-www redirect should come first in order to avoid a double redirect when requesting `http://www.example.com` (ie. HTTP and www).

Note that you should only use this type of HTTP to HTTPS redirect when you are behind a proxy server that is handling the SSL. Otherwise, the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request header could be faked by a malicious client request (this, however, should be handled by your proxy server).

---

These two rules can be combined into 1 rule if you wish:

```
# Canonical redirect (no-www and HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for a detailed answer, but it still shows the same "incorrect redirection" error

Comment: If solution doesn't work, try to debug PHP `$_SERVER` variable for some another header, which show HTTPS usage. In my case it was `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL']`, so .htaccess rule was `# http to https redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Protocol} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`