# .htaccess error - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-500

I have this .htaccess file to redirect `http://` to `https://`

I also did `www.` to root domain redirection!

`www.` to root domain works! however `https://` redirection doesn't!
If I set `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` to `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` or `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =!on` I get a browser error:

> **The example.com page isn’t working**
>
> mysite.com redirected you too many times.
>
> Try clearing your cookies.
>
> *ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*

One edit I did gave me a 500 error but I reverted that back to how it was before! all I did was change: `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` to     `RewriteRule(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` or `RewriteRule (.*)https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

#### Anyone have any Ideas on how to fix this issue?

This is my entire `.htaccess` file!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on          [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://antimalwareprogram.co%{REQUEST_URI}     [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

Yes, this will create a redirect loop. The logic is wrong. What this says is... if HTTPS is "on" then redirect to HTTPS. You should be checking if HTTPS is "off" (or "not on", ie. `!on`).

(By removing the spaces between the arguments you likely created a rewrite loop, hence the 500 error. Spaces are delimiters in Apache config files.)

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

This handles both the HTTPS and www canonical redirects. You don't need the first rule. You don't need the `<IfModule>` container either.

Change the `302` to `301` only when you are sure it's working OK.

Make sure you've cleared your browser cache before testing. 301s get cached hard by the browser.

---

**UPDATE:** If this still gives you the same error (a redirect loop) then it's possible that your SSL is managed by a front-end proxy, not your application server. If this is the case then you won't be able to use the `HTTPS` server variable. See these related questions:

- [http to https redirection through htaccess: incorrect redirection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285014/http-to-https-redirection-through-htaccess-incorrect-redirection-error)
- [htaccess rewrite - too many redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743283/htaccess-rewrite-too-many-redirects)

---

It seems that in this case, `ENV:HTTPS` (an environment variable) needed to be used in place of `HTTPS` (Apache server variable). Note, however, that this is non-standard / server specific, as it implies a front-end proxy is being used to manage the SSL.