# Troubleshooting infinite redirection when redirecting www to https using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, apache2

I have a particular problem as in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled conf files I know how to do it.
But in the server which is not mine because my client use its own server I need to use .htaccess. And its the only thing I can control.

My .htaccess file is this one

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /public/admin.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin /public/admin.php [L]

RewriteRule ^owner/(.*)$ /public/owner.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^owner /public/owner.php [L]

RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /public/index.php?lang=fr&url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fr /public/index.php?lang=fr [L]

RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /public/index.php?lang=en&url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^en /public/index.php?lang=en [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !("fr"|"en"|app.manifest|website.manifest|public|css|js|images|video|sounds|ajax|chat|googlea3bd4e094535f86e.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(public)
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1
```

Now I need to redirect http to https and a domain name to an other as two domains point to the same website.

I tried everything I found on the web, but with my previous .htaccess commands everything is failing. Do you have any idea?

Examples of what I tried to ad :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

At the beginning or at the end of the file. Not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

same thing

this one is working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Which means that it does redirect properly http://example.com to https://www.example.com
but when I do the same to redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com it says "Do not redirect properly" as it seems to not consider the port condition and redirect infinitely.

What do you think about this guys?

THanks

Julien Mehl Vettori

Comment: Is your application server behind a proxy that manages the SSL connection? That would explain the redirect loop as the application server is always communicating on HTTP (port 80) to the proxy. For example, see the following related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285014/http-to-https-redirection-through-htaccess-incorrect-redirection-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164097/htaccess-https-too-many-redirects-works-not-on-specific-hosting